# subtract dates in workflow table with type and datestamps

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have a table with 3 columns:

```
resid      type        date
```

The table is used to track steps in a workflow and a specific resid can exist multiple with different type id(numbers) and datestamps.
I want to calculate the time used between two typeshift - i.e, 1 and 17 on a specific resid

I have tried with a sql-plus syntax like this
and also tried to use aliases: 
Any suggestions?

```
select resid, date - date 
from tablename
where resid, date in
(select resid, date from tablename
where type='1')
and 
where resid, date in
(select resid, date from tablename
where type='17')
and tablename.resid=tablename.resid
```

Comment: Will there only ever be one each of type 1 and 17 for each `resid`; and will there always be one of each? If not (say type 1 exists but 17 doesn't (yet), or there are two 17s) what should it show? Sample data and expected output would be helpful.

Comment: what is the problem?  please show sample data or error messages

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.resid, a."type" type1, a."date" date1, b."type" type17, b."date" date17, b."date" - a."date" AS date_diff
  FROM tablename a JOIN tablename b ON a.resid = b.resid AND b."type" = '17'
 WHERE a."type" = '1' AND a.resid = :resid
```

Please do not use oracle reserved words as column names.
When (resid, type) is unique you can do:

```
SELECT :resid resid, 
      (select "date" FROM tablename WHERE resid = :resid AND "type" = '17') -
      (select "date" FROM tablename WHERE resid = :resid AND "type" = '1') date_diff
  FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score 1):

Your attempted query is missing parentheses around the column list before the `in` - so should be `where (resid, date in)` - but also has `and where` which isn't valid, and probably other issues. Mostly it doesn't do what you want, not least because both `date` values are coming from the same row (for type 1) so subtracting them will always give zero.

You could use conditional aggregation:

```
select resid,
  min(case when type_id = 17 then date_stamp end)
    - min(case when type_id = 1 then date_stamp end) as diff
from tablename
where type_id in (1, 17) -- optional
and resid = :some_value
group by resid;
```

The `case` gives either null or the date stamp for each matching row; the aggregation then gives you a single value from those (favouring not-null ones).

If only one of the type IDs exists then the difference will be null.

You might want to change the `min()` for 17 to `max()` if there may be multiples - depends what you really need.

Quick demo:

```
with tablename(resid, type_id, date_stamp) as (
  select 1, 1, sysdate - 10 from dual
  union all select 1, 17, sysdate - 7 from dual
  union all select 2, 1, sysdate - 5 from dual
  union all select 2, 17, sysdate - 3 from dual
  union all select 3, 1, sysdate - 10 from dual
)
select resid,
  min(case when type_id = 17 then date_stamp end)
    - min(case when type_id = 1 then date_stamp end) as diff
from tablename
where type_id in (1, 17) -- optional
--and resid = 2
group by resid;

     RESID       DIFF
---------- ----------
         1          3
         2          2
         3
```